# Selecting ace:checkboxButton in nested c:forEach affects all iterations

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, jsf-2.2, icefaces

I'm showing a questionnaire in a nested `<c:forEach>` in which an `<ace:checkboxButton>` is used to choose an answer. The code boils down to this:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.questions}" var="question">
    <c:forEach items="#{question.answers}" var="answer">
        <ace:checkboxButton value="#{answer.response}">
            <ace:ajax event="action" render="@form" />
        </ace:checkboxButton>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

This seems quite simple, but in fact, when I select an answer for one question, it also selects the same answer for all other questions.

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What if you use `<ui:repeat>` instead?

Comment: I tried, same result. It's weird, because names appear correctly in the form, so checkboxes should too... :-/ Thanks for edit.